# How to query against legacy data that needs to be cleaned up?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, performance, query-performance

I have an existing SQL Server DB with 3 tables (note: this is a made up example, but modelled after a real problem).

- **Artists** : contains music artists
- **MusicRecords** : contains information on music records produced by an artists
- **LabelAndArtists** : lists all the labels that have published the artist

[image: Music Database]

For the whole life of the application MusicRecords were gotten by Artist.

```
SELECT * FROM [MusicRecords] WHERE [ArtistID] = 10
```

Now we want to start querying MusicRecords based off of which Label published the MusicRecord. However we were lax in the past when putting Label information in the system. Some Labels were prefixed by 'Label-', other times the Label would just be NULL in the MusicRecord.

If there is exactly 1 LabelAndArtists record for an artist the business is comfortable assuming the LabelAndArtist Label is the Label for the MusicRecord.

We came up with a few ways we could query off of Label.

1. Create a `VIEW` that can normalize Label name so we can query off of it.
2. Create a `FUNCTION` that returns a `TABLE` of ArtistIDs with that a normalized Label that we can join to Artists.
3. Create a Mapping table between Artists and normalized Labels.
4. Fix our Labels.

The obvious answer would be to fix our Labels. However due to application constraints I am not sure how viable that would be.

Are any of our ways the better than others to query MusicRecords by Label? Is there another way to get MusicRecords by Label?

SQL to recreate:

```
---------- Artists ----------
CREATE TABLE [Artists]
(
    [ArtistID] [int] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](512) NOT NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Artists] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Artists] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED  
    (
        [ArtistID]
    ) 
    ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

---------- MusicRecords ----------
CREATE TABLE [MusicRecords]
(
    [MusicRecordID] [int] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ArtistID] [int] NOT NULL, 
    [Title] [varchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [Label] [varchar](512) NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [MusicRecords] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MusicRecords] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED  
    (
        [MusicRecordID]
    ) 
    ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

ALTER TABLE [MusicRecords] ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MusicRecords_Artist] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [ArtistID]
    ) REFERENCES [Artists] (
        [ArtistID]
    )   ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MusicRecords_ArtistID] ON [MusicRecords]
(
    [ArtistID],
    [MusicRecordID]
)
GO

---------- LabelAndArtists ----------
CREATE TABLE [LabelAndArtists]
(
    [LabelAndArtistsID] [int] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ArtistID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LabelName] [varchar](512) NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [LabelAndArtists] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_LabelAndArtists] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED  
    (
        [LabelAndArtistsID]
    ) 
    ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LabelAndArtists_ArtistID] ON [LabelAndArtists]
(
    [LabelAndArtistsID],
    [ArtistID]
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [LabelAndArtists] ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_LabelAndArtists_Artist] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [ArtistID]
    ) REFERENCES [Artists] (
        [ArtistID]
    )   ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

-- Possible VIEW Solution
CREATE VIEW [VW_MusicRecordsWithNormalizedLabel]
AS
    SELECT
        Label = REPLACE(COALESCE
        (
            m.Label, 
            CASE WHEN 
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT m2.[LabelName])
                    FROM [LabelAndArtists] m2 with(nolock)
                    WHERE m2.[ArtistID] = m.[ArtistID]
                    AND m2.[LabelName] IS NOT NULL
                ) = 1 
                THEN 
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 m2.[LabelName] 
                    FROM [LabelAndArtists] m2 with(nolock)
                    WHERE  m2.[ArtistID] = m.[ArtistID]
                    ORDER BY m2.[LabelName] DESC
                ) 
                ELSE NULL 
                END
        ), 'Label-', ''), 
        m.[ArtistID],
        m.[Title]
    FROM [MusicRecords] m
GO
DECLARE @Label varchar(512) = '15'
SELECT * FROM [VW_MusicRecordsWithNormalizedLabel] WHERE Label = @Label

-- Possible FUNCTION Solution
CREATE FUNCTION [Artists_GetByLabel] (@LabelName [varchar](512))
    RETURNS @ArtistsIDs TABLE (ID int NOT NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @ArtistsIDs
        SELECT ArtistID 
        FROM LabelAndArtists a with (nolock) 
        WHERE a.LabelName = REPLACE(@LabelName, 'Label-', '')
        UNION
        SELECT a.ArtistID 
        FROM Artists a with (nolock) 
        JOIN MusicRecords mr with (nolock) on (a.ArtistID = mr.ArtistID)
        WHERE mr.Label = REPLACE(@LabelName, 'Label-', '')
    RETURN
END
GO
DECLARE @Label varchar(512) = '15'
SELECT * 
FROM [MusicRecords] m
JOIN [Artists_GetByLabel](@Label) abl on (abl.ID = m.ArtistID)

---------- Test Data ----------
DECLARE @RowCount [int] = 1
WHILE @RowCount < 150000
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO [Artists] ([Name]) VALUES ('ArtistName' + CONVERT(varchar(128), NewID())) 
    DECLARE @ArtistID [int] = @@IDENTITY
    DECLARE @LabelTypeA [varchar] (512) = 'Label-' + Convert(varchar(512), @RowCount)
    DECLARE @LabelTypeB [varchar] (512) =  Convert(varchar(512), @RowCount)

    INSERT INTO [MusicRecords] ([ArtistID], [Title], [Label]) VALUES (@ArtistID, 'Title' + CONVERT(varchar(128), NewID()), @LabelTypeA)
    INSERT INTO [MusicRecords] ([ArtistID], [Title], [Label]) VALUES (@ArtistID, 'Title' + CONVERT(varchar(128), NewID()), @LabelTypeA)
    INSERT INTO [MusicRecords] ([ArtistID], [Title], [Label]) VALUES (@ArtistID, 'Title' + CONVERT(varchar(128), NewID()), @LabelTypeB)
    INSERT INTO [MusicRecords] ([ArtistID], [Title], [Label]) VALUES (@ArtistID, 'Title' + CONVERT(varchar(128), NewID()), NULL)
    INSERT INTO [MusicRecords] ([ArtistID], [Title], [Label]) VALUES (@ArtistID, 'Title' + CONVERT(varchar(128), NewID()), NULL)

    INSERT INTO [LabelAndArtists] ([ArtistID], [LabelName]) VALUES (@ArtistID, @LabelTypeA)
    INSERT INTO [LabelAndArtists] ([ArtistID], [LabelName]) VALUES (@ArtistID, NULL)

    SET @RowCount = @RowCount + 1 
END
```

Comment: Fix the data. Other recommendations are hard to rank since we don't know how bad the data is, how much work normalizing is,  how much data there is, etc. If it's truly legacy data then you should be able to modify it or create a copy of it that can be properly normalized.